# Azure Functions using SignalR without output binding

Tags: azure-functions, signalr, azure-signalr

I have a number of Azure functions which have HTTP input and output bindings. Within those functions, I would like to send a message to clients via SignalR.

There seem to be a number of ways to do this and I'm not sure which to use. Based upon my (mis)understanding, I have these options:

1. Output bindings. This is what the Azure Functions SignalR docs show, but I would prefer to keep my output bindings as HTTP.
2. Deriving a class from `ServerlessHub` and sending messages via its `Clients` object. This seems a good way to do it if you want to have SignalR input trigger functions. I also didn't see where to specify the connection information here.
3. Creating a `HubConnection` and `IHubProxy`, then using the proxy to invoke methods. This seems like the ASP.NET Core way but not necessarily the Functions way.

Are these options correct? What approach should I take?